# Эффект медленного появления картинки

Tags: html, css, javascript

Подскажите, как реализовать эффект медленного появления картинки при наведении на текст с ссылкой? Причём картинка должна появляться сзади этого текста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xrxpcnn/2/)

Comment: *Оффтоп* Что-то ответы становятся всё короче и короче ))